# Scala: implicitly convert to a generic subtype

Tags: scala, akka

My code heavily uses Akka and untyped actors.

An example of typical logic is as follows:

```
val myFuture: Future[Any] = akka.pattern.AskSupport.ask(myActorRef, myMessage)

val completedLogic: Future[Unit] = myFuture.map(myFunction)
```

myFunction then contains a strongly typed signature as follows:

```
def myFunction(): (Option[MyStronglyTypedClass]) => Unit = {
    (myOption: Option[MyStronglyTypedClass]) => myOption foreach (myObject => // do some logic
}
```

I know that myFuture will **always** contain an instance of MyStronglyTypedClass *or null* for this particular actor. I will also know this for other actor/future/function combinations.

My problem comes when I look to create an implicit conversion from the `Future[Any]` to the `Option[MyStronglyTypedClass]` or `Option[MyOtherStronglyTypedClass]`

The implicit conversion will just do a null check and one other piece of logic before creating the Option

How do I go about performing this implicit conversion from Any to a subtype, or is it even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should, instead, convert to `Future[Option[MyStronglyTypedClass]]`:

```
def asMyStronglyTypedClass(x: Any): Option[MyStronglyTypedClass] = x match {
  case null => None
  case ...
}

// this will fail if myFuture fails or asMyStronglyTypedClass throws
val typedFuture = myFuture.map(asMyStronglyTypedClass)
```

and do what you want with this future. E.g.

```
typedFuture.onSuccess(myFunction)
```

EDIT: I missed you already have a `map`. In this case the issue is that you don't need to convert `Future[Any]` to `Option`, but its result (i.e. `Any`). You can write e.g. `myFuture.map(asMyStronglyTypedClass).map(myFunction)` or `myFuture.map(x => myFunction(asMyStronglyTypedClass(x)))`. You could also make `asMyStronglyTypedClass` implicit and write `myFuture.map(x => myFunction(x))`. I still think it isn't a good idea, as it could get applied somewhere you *don't* expect.

If you really want to write `myFuture.map(myFunction)`, you'll need a *different* implicit conversion to make the compiler understand:

```
implicit def contraMap(f: Option[MyStronglyTypedClass] => Unit): Any => Unit = 
  x => f(asMyStronglyTypedClass(x))
```

Of course, these can be made generic over your types, as mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Thanks, but we have retry logic elsewhere for exceptions, but for nulls we wish to proceed as these are allowed. The above solution will not work if I need to have a function for each MyStronglyTypedClass

Comment: The point is that you shouldn't be converting to `Option[...]`, but to `Future[Option[...]]`. Otherwise you lose the point of `Future`. You can make this conversion implicit, if you want (though it would be a bad idea in most circumstances). Also, if the logic is the same, you can have `asStronglyTyped[T](x: Any): Option[T]` instead.

Comment: If you _really_ want, you can use `Await.result` to wait for the result and to convert it to `Option[...]` in whatever way you want. Again, this is a bad idea and loses any benefits from using `Future`.

Comment: Thanks, my reasoning was that map would only be performed on the Future after it completed, so that is why I thought I could convert it to an Option at that point. What benefit of Future am I losing if I do this? Just trying to understand your suggestion better. I like the asStronglyTyped function though, that is what I'll try and implement

Comment: I've explained a bit more.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I understand everything you are saying above apart from the contraMap....why does it have to be the opposite way?!

Comment: Because `myFuture.map` takes `Any => B` as argument, and `myFunction`'s type `Option[MyStronglyTypedClass] => Unit` doesn't fit this. So you need to convert from one to the other, and the compiler won't insert an implicit conversion from `Any` to `Option[...]` inside `myFunction` to fix up the types like that.

Comment: There's also `akka.pattern.AskSupport.ask(myActorRef, myMessage).mapTo[Option[MyStronglyTypedClass]].map(myFunction)` which can be used for your case, when you're sure, that there is always an `Option[MyStronlgyTypedClass]` returned within the Future. See http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/futures.html#Use_With_Actors (second box)

Answer (score 1):

Impliciy converting from Any to something else is something that you should never do because it effectively switches off Scala's type system. Converting the type of a future in a safe fashion can be done using

```
myFuture.mapTo[Option[MyStronglyTypedClass]]
```